# Android View: onMeasure() onLayout() onDraw() how to limit calls

Tags: android, layout, view, ondraw, onmeasure

I am really curious how to limit the calls of these methods `onMeasure()`, `onLayout()`, `onDraw()`. Since I know they are called everytime the `View` need to resize if any other `View` is being added. Am I thinking right? I want to know how to avoid checking the size and setting the height and width (especially during `onMasure()`) if the rest of the `Views` has got exactly the same dimensions. In my application `View` is in fragment where I have got `<ScrollView>` and I `<include>` more `layouts` there:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="vertical"
        >
            <include layout="@layout/firts"/>
            <include layout="@layout/second"/>
            <include layout="@layout/third"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The methods responsible for setting the view are called about 10 times. I want to set the dimensions just once because I `@Override`'d them to do some more work there and load the options of the `HTML` (those views are `WebView`'s). I want to load data only once but since the methods in the title are called multiple times I load things many times. It causes some kind of shutter on my screen. Is there any trick to check the dimensions and if they are different then set them again or is there a way to prevent calling these methods?

**@EDIT**
This is what I'm doing in `onMeasure()`method:

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec,
                    int heightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        System.out.println("Measure size...");
        float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        float height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        setMinimumWidth(Math.round(getWidth()/density));
        setMinimumHeight(Math.round(height/density*2/5));
        this.HTML.prepareViewWidth(Math.round(getWidth()/density), Math.round(height/density*2/5));
    }
```

The rest HTML (base scripts which are needed) is loaded in `onAttachedToWindow` but I have no idea where to put this method: `loadDataWithBaseURL`. I tried each of the mentioned method onMeasure, onLayout, onDraw, but that is done 10 times.

Comment: so you "load the options" in the wrong places, tried `onAttachedToWindow` or `onFinishInflate`?

Comment: @pskink hi, thanks for the comment. I loaded them in `onAttachedToWindow` that's the same but didn't try `onFinishInflate`, gonna check it

Comment: `onAttachedToWindow` is called 10 times? so it is attached to root window 10 times instead once?

Comment: @pskink I ulpoaded the question to let you know what I want to achieve

Comment: @pskink when I do it like in the question the height which I put in `onMeasure` is ignored

Comment: @pskink i tried `onFinishInflate` but the method is not called